# In MS Access, how to select record on form1 after adding from form2?

Tags: forms, ms-access, select, record

This is my scenario (MS Access 2007):

On Form1 I have a list of records (Orders). Form1 has a button that launches Form2.

Form2 is used for creating new Orders. The "Save" button on Form2 uses VBA to save the record, close the form and requery Form1:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCloseWindow
Forms!Orders.Requery
```

The next step I'd like to be able to do is have the new record selected automatically on Form1. My guess is it's somehow done with `DoCmd.FindRecord`? I can't figure it out -- any help is very appreciated.

Thanks,
Stewart

Comment: I think you'd be better off with a user interface that takes care of all of this for you. In general, instead of using multiple forms, you'd use a single list form and a detail subform so that you could control interaction directly all in one place. Of course, you'd definitely have to use "grown-up" VBA, instead of the commands translated from the menu that you're quoting in the code snippet above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would depend on whether the application has a single user or multiple users.  In a multiuser scenario, simply getting the most recently added Order would not necessarily return the one YOU have just entered. But if it's only you, getting the most recently added value would do that.

You can find the row with  the max(orderid) if you're using an autoincrementing key; or find the row with the max(orderDateTime) if your orders are timestamped; or simply have the datasource for the  Orderslist form be sorted by either of those values, descending, and reposition to the first record after a Requery.

Comment: A better question: if I use `Forms!Orders.Recordset FindFirst "ID = " & the ID`, how can I get the ID from the autonumber column that was just saved?

Comment: Ah some googling figured it out for me -- I'm now doing FindFirst and looking for an order with the same name and date. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you found it. What's the purpose of finding the newly inserted order in the master-list? Usually it would be so you can continue working with that order. So why not stay on the new-order-entry form instead of bouncing back to the master list?  Couldn't you have the appropriate menu options on the new order form?